# How to display all posts in a blog application using Rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to implement a blog application in my app.But i am getting the following  error after saving the posts.

## Error:

```
NoMethodError in Homes#blog

Showing C:/Site/library_management1/app/views/homes/blog.html.erb where line #19 raised:

undefined method `name' for #<Array:0x21896a0>
```

Actually My blog implementation story is like this.When a logged in user will add his name and comment in required place and clicked on submit button all blogs will saved as well as display.All comments should visible to all logged in users belongs to this app.Suppose one user wants to reply/edit then he/she can do this.

My codes are as follows.

## views/homes/blog.html.erb:

```
<% if current_user %>
<div class="totaldiv">
  <div class="navdiv"><span>STUDENT INFORMATION</span><span>Logged in as <%= current_user.email %></span></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div id="leftsidebtn">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="/homes/issuebooks">Book issue</a></li>
   <li><a href="/homes/availablebooks">Books Available</a></li>
   <li><a href="/homes/magazines?user_id=<%= current_user.id %>">Magazines Purchase</a></li>
  <li><a href="/sessions/removeuser">Log Out</a></li>
 </ul>  
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="restdiv" id="ex3" >
<center>
 <%= form_for :blogs,:url => {:action => 'savecomments',:id => current_user.id } do |f| %>
 <p>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <%= f.text_field :name,placeholder:"Enter your name" %>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="Comment">Comment:</label>
  <%= f.text_area :body,:class => "blog-navigation",placeholder:"Type your comment here" %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.submit "Add Comments",:class =>"btn btn-success" %>
</p>
 <% end %>
 <% if params[:id] %>
 <h1>Comments</h1>
 <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
<div class="blog-site">
<div class="name-site">
 <%= blog.name %>
</div>
<div class="message-site">
  <%= blog.body %>
</div>
<div class="reply-site">
  <%= link_to 'Replay',homes_blog_path %>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
</center>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

## controller/homes_controller.rb:

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
     before_filter :authenticate_admin!,only: [:admin]
    def index

    end
    def admin

    end
    def managebooks
        @books=Book.new
        if params[:id]
            @books=Book.find(params[:id])
            @book=Book.all
        end
    end
    def savebooks
        @books=Book.new(params[:books])
        if @books.save
            flash[:notice]="Data has submitted successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'managebooks',:id => @books.id
        else
            flash[:notice]="Data couldnot submitted successfully"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'managebooks'
        end
    end
    def remove
        @books=Book.find(params[:id])
        @books.destroy
    end
    def books

    end
    def showbooks
        @books=Book.all
    end
    def searchbooks
        @books=Book.all
    end
    def member
        @users=User.new
    end
    def registration
        @users=User.new
    end
    def savedata
        @users=User.new(params[:users])
        if @users.save
            flash[:notice]="Data has submitted successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'member'
        else
            flash[:notice]="Data could not submitted successfully"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'registration'
        end
    end
    def issuebooks
        @issues=Issue.new
    end
    def savedissuebooks
        @issues=Issue.new(params[:issues])
        if @issues.save
            flash[:notice]="information has saved successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'member'
        else
            flash[:notice]="Data couldnot saved"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'issuebooks'
        end
    end
    def availablebooks

        @books=Book.all
    end
    def userissues
        @issues=Issue.all
    end
    def magazine
        @magazines=Magazine.new
    end
    def savemagazines
        @users=User.find(params[:id])
        @magazines=Magazine.new(params[:magazines])
        @magazines.user_id=@users.id
        if @magazines.save
            flash[:notice]="Data submitted successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => "member"
        else
            flash[:notice]="Data could not saved"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'magazines'
        end
    end
    def magazineissue
        @magazines=Magazine.all
        @users=User.find @magazines.first.user_id
    end
    def blog
        if params[:id]
            @blogs=Blog.find(params[:id])
            @blogs=Blog.all
        else
        @blogs=Blog.new
        end
    end
    def savecomments
        @users=User.find(params[:id])
        @blogs=Blog.new(params[:blogs])
        @blogs.user_id=@users.id
        if @blogs.save
            flash[:notice]="Comment has been posted successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => "blog",:id => params[:id]
        else
            flash[:notice]="Comment could not saved"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'blog'
        end
    end
end
```

## model/blog.rb

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :name
  validates :name, :presence => true, :length => {:in => 3..10}
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Please check my all codes and let me to know where i did the mistake and kindly help me to make this blog application correctly according to my story which is explained above.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point you to a blog post explaining how to debug a rails application yourself: http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

It's important to understand what the rails error-message is trying to tell you:

> undefined method `name` for Array:0x21896a0

It's calling `.name` on some array.

> Showing C:/Site/library_management1/app/views/homes/blog.html.erb where line #19 raised:

It's doing this in `blog.html.erb` on line 19 which I suppose is this part here:

```
 <%= form_for :blogs,:url => {:action => 'savecomments',:id => current_user.id } do |f| %>
 <p>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <%= f.text_field :name,placeholder:"Enter your name" %>
</p>
```

This form is trying to call `.name` on the nested object which you defined to be `:blogs` in order to get the `:name` property for the `f.text_field`. So what is the object that the form is trying to work with?

> NoMethodError in Homes#blog

Looking at the controller code of `Homes#blog` to see where a possible form object comes from:

```
def blog
    if params[:id]
        @blogs=Blog.find(params[:id])
        @blogs=Blog.all
    else
    @blogs=Blog.new
    end
end
```

So the only thing that could be an array is `@blogs = Blog.all`. And this code does not look like it makes much sense to me. Why are you doing a `Blog.find` just to replace it with `Blog.all` in the next line?